Oracle Apex Once column value saved cannot be modified
I have an interactive grid.
select alpha, beta, gamma from vectors;

In this grid, once a value for beta is saved, it shouldn't be  allowed to modify.
So i create a new record:
alpha = A1
Beta = B1
Gamma = C1

After this new record is saved, alpha and gamma can be modified but not Beta.
How can this be achieved?

This can be managed using the "Read Only" attribute. Column values can be referenced using the bind variable syntax (:COLUMN). No dynamic action is needed for this.
Example:
There is a table mytable. The column ITEM can only be inserted, not updated.
create table mytable (
    id       number generated by default on null as identity
             constraint mytable_id_pk primary key,
    item     varchar2(100 char),
    price    number
);

In the interactive grid, set the read only condition of type "Expression", code :ID IS NOT NULL and make sure to set "Execute" to "For each Row" since this needs to be evaluated for every row. Now when a new row is added, the column ITEM is editable but once saved it's read only.

